# ??? com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue

Tags: react-native

In the firebase crash report, it's not showing any line number its coming with "???"
Am not find any answer related to this Unknown source that happening only in 8.1.0 android version

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.1

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue (Unknown Source:27)
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt (Unknown Source:17)
com.facebook.react.g.a.a (Unknown Source:44)
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportSoftException (Unknown Source:16)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:148)
com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:21)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (Unknown Source:37)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```